# How to keep and access data in BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

If I understand Android manual, `BroadcastReceiver` is treated as stateless entity, so I should keep a service which will serve as data container (those are my conclusions).

As per each request for data access I should execute `startService` (?) -- I can pass this way data to service, but how to get data back?

I mean in recommended way? I could think of passing "out" data, and service on completion would change it, so when `startService` returns I could check the data I sent in order to retrieve the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I understand Android manual, BroadcastReceiver is treated as stateless entity, so I should keep a service which will serve as data container (those are my conclusions).

Having a service around solely to hold onto data will make your users dislike you, and is no guarantee that the data will stick around anyway. The user and the OS can and will get rid of your process whenever they wish.

Please use files (e.g., database, `SharedPreferences`) for holding data that needs to survive between process invocations.

Comment: It have a service anyway, because it launched receiver in the first place.

Comment: @macias: If by "it launched receiver" you mean that the service calls `registerRecevier()`, then simply have the `BroadcastReceiver` be an inner class of the `Service`, in which case both objects have access to the `Service`'s data members. This does not eliminate the need for a persistent data store, though, for any data that should live past the lifetime of the service, and services do not live forever.

Comment: Thank you. This is valuable, but I would like to keep things clean and have separate files (and also learn more). I will keep the data in preferences as you (and just8blaze) said, but I also need to communicate with service as well.

Comment: @macias: Then use a static data member or something as an in-memory cache of the persistent data.

Comment: To avoid long discussion in comments here is the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859774/how-to-send-and-get-data-between-service-and-broadcastreceiver

Comment: Hmm, this is a good idea even for making receiver stateful. After all, I can have only 1 instance of receiver. Another +1 :-D

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use a service for this, [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) are very useful for storing some key/value pair data.