# How to send and get data between Service and BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

In my previous question: [How to keep and access data in BroadcastReceiver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858208/how-to-keep-and-access-data-in-broadcastreceiver) I've got excellent answers, but here I focus on this.

There is BroadcastReceiver and there is Service. I would like to send some data from the receiver to service and get the data back. The party which initiates the transfer is receiver, not the service.

For the sake of the simplicity, let's say that receiver waits for SCREEN_ON and then asks service "is this a birthday of the user", and server returns true or false.

If I am not mistaken I should attach my data that goes to Service to the Intent, and call `startService`, but how to get data back?

Comment: To be blunt, your fundamental design is flawed IMHO. The service, not the receiver, should be "the party which initiates the transfer". The receiver is merely a means of finding out about an event, nothing more -- it delegates handling of that event to the service for processing.

Comment: @CommonsWare, how come? Receiver receives the event (like SCREEN_ON), thus it is the only one who can proceeds further.

Comment: "thus it is the only one who can proceeds further" -- and it "proceeds further" by delegating handling of that event to the service for processing.

Comment: @CommonsWare, not exactly, receiver asks service about some data, once it has the data it acts appropriately. Btw. I would not like to discuss IF this approach is good or bad, either receiver can communicate with service or not. I believe it can (vide Android manual), the only remaining piece is -- how. Assuming this is not illegal black magic, I would like to stick with it.

Comment: Hear to @CommonsWare they know what they said. You MUST delegate this task to the service, the service will start the petition and recover the data. If you don't want to hear them, you will fail. The BroadCastReceiver has a limit timout of 10 seconds, you know what happens then...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't really do this the way you've described. @CommonsWare is correct, **your chosen architecture is flawed**.

`BroadcastReceiver`s are short-lived. Therefore they cannot make any asynchronous calls and they cannot perform any tasks that take a "significant amount of time". Your `BroadcastReceiver` gets triggered by a certain event and if you need to do any significant amount of work due to that event you will need to delegate that work to a `Service`.

Normally (for example: within an `Activity`), if you wanted to request information from a `Service` you could either bind to the `Service` and make a synchronous call to the service to request the data you want OR you could call the service asynchronously (ie: send an `Intent` to it) and then listen for the returned result (using a `BroadcastReceiver`). Neither of these methods works from a `BroadcastReceiver` because a `BroadcastReceiver` cannot bind to a `Service` and it cannot make asynchronous calls.

**EDIT: Copied relevant information from the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) for reference here**

> **Receiver Lifecycle**
>
> A `BroadcastReceiver` object is only valid for the duration of the call
>   to `onReceive(Context, Intent)`. Once your code returns from this
>   function, the system considers the object to be finished and no longer
>   active.
>
> This has important repercussions to what you can do in an
>   `onReceive(Context, Intent)` implementation: anything that requires
>   asynchronous operation is not available, because you will need to
>   return from the function to handle the asynchronous operation, but at
>   that point the `BroadcastReceiver` is no longer active and thus the
>   system is free to kill its process before the asynchronous operation
>   completes.
>
> In particular, you may not show a dialog or bind to a service from
>   within a `BroadcastReceiver`. For the former, you should instead use the
>   `NotificationManager` API. For the latter, you can use
>   `Context.startService()` to send a command to the service.

Comment: If connecting to service is such a bad idea, then why Android manual explicitly describes how to connect to it -- "you can use Context.startService() to send a command to the service"? "if you need to do any significant amount of work" -- I didn't say a word about it.

Comment: This reference in the documentation is correct. What it suggests you do is to use the `BroadcastReceiver` to catch the event, then you call `startService()` to send a command to the `Service` which then does the work. Using `startService()` is not the same as **binding to a service**. The `BroadcastReceiver` is just use to catch the event trigger and forward the information to the `Service`. I've copied some relevant information from the Android documentation into my answer.

Comment: So it is more "fire & forget" approach then? Gee, that's really bad because it leaves me with only option -- keeping static member in service and using it directly from receiver (no need for copying the manual, I quoted it, so I know where it is).

Comment: If your receiver and your service are running in the same process, I see no reason why you shouldn't share access to a static variable. IMHO that's a perfectly valid data exchange mechanism. I quoted the manual because it is relevant to the discussion. Even if you know where it is maybe someone else who is reading this question/answer does not.

Comment: Of course technically it is valid, but it is hackish. Entire static object is fully exposed to receiver. In my case I wrote the receiver and service, so I will live with it, but normally you don't expose everything because you want access to just one method (from the "shared" object).

Comment: Alternative: make the static object private, create a public static method that calls the method you want to expose on the private static object.

Comment: Yes, you are right -- scrap my previous comment. Anyway, my developer esthetics would be satisfied with real communication with the service (via system), not directly via calling statics methods.

Answer (score 0):

Use a session!
Save the data in a session:

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        SessionManager session = new SessionManager(context);
        // get user data from session
        HashMap<String, Object> user = session.getUserDetails();

    // name
    m_userId = (int)user.get(SessionManager.KEY_ID);


    m_context = context;

    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");

    wl.acquire();

    // Put here YOUR code.
    //Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm !!!!!!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // For example



    wl.release();
}
```